# Unable to alter file with sed when file is created in bash script

Tags: bash, git-bash, windows-11

Running Windows (Git Bash).

Said script is supposed to make a copy off httpd.conf to httpd.conf.ORIG and then run sed on the .ORIG file and redirect output back to .conf.

HOWEVER.

Sed will not make changes and save to the httpd.conf file if I make a copy of the .conf file to a .ORIG version inside of the script (as shown below). I have to remove the if statement and make the copy on the command line manually and then run the script. In doing so, it works...

Why in the world is this? (I only am using redirection here instead -i with sed on the original .conf file because that also will not work).

It has me totally puzzled.

Script in question is below:

```
if [[ ! -f "/c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf.ORIG" ]]
then
    cp /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf.ORIG
fi

WORKINGDIR=$(echo "$PWD" | sed -e 's/^\/c/C:/g;s/\//\\\\/g')
ROOTLOC=$(grep "DocumentRoot \"" /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf.ORIG)
DIRLOC=$(grep -m 1 "<Directory \"" /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf.ORIG)

sed "s~${DIRLOC}~<Directory \"${WORKINGDIR}\">~g;s~$ROOTLOC~DocumentRoot \"${WORKINGDIR}\"~g" /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf.ORIG > /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

Comment: You need to use the suffix `-i` to make changes

Comment: Please see part of original message above:

"Why in the world is this? (I only am using redirection here instead -i with sed on the original .conf file because that also will not work)."

Comment: please add example of content of your config file and example of what you would like to see inside so we can test the solution

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting the following solution (did not test):

```
set -x  # enabled only for debug
if [[ ! -f "/c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf.ORIG" ]]; then
    cp /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf.ORIG
fi
WORKINGDIR=$(echo "$PWD" | sed -e '{s|^/c|/C:|g; s|/|\\\\|g}')
ROOTLOC=$(grep "DocumentRoot \"" /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf.ORIG)
DIRLOC=$(grep -m 1 "<Directory \"" /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf.ORIG)
sed -i '{s|'${DIRLOC}'|<Directory "'${WORKINGDIR}'">|g; s|'$ROOTLOC'|DocumentRoot "'${WORKINGDIR}'"|g}' /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf
set +x  # enabled only for debug

# when it works disable/delete all debug lines
```

1. Using `set -x` and `set +x` to debug the actual expanded commands.
2. Using `|` as replacment separator in `sed` command.
3. Using `{}` braces to combine `sed` instructions together.
4. Using `'` quote, as the main quoting tool in `sed` command.

Note that you might need to double quote BASH variables with `"` if the expanded variable contains   one or more spaces.

Like this:

```
sed -i '{s|'"${DIRLOC}"'|<Directory "'"${WORKINGDIR}"'">|g; s|'"$ROOTLOC"'|DocumentRoot "'"${WORKINGDIR}"'"|g}' /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed response. I tried all your suggestions and in examining with set -x, all the expansions are correct and it runs flawlessly (with -i added back in). But the file is not edited. And if i run it w/o -i as it displays in the terminal, it also shows unedited. So weird. Any other suggestions? :)

Comment: For reference, here is set output for the sed line.

`++ sed -i '{s|<Directory' '"C:\xampp">|<Directory "C:\\xampp\\apache\\conf">|g; s|DocumentRoot' '"C:\xampp"|DocumentRoot "C:\\xampp\\apache\\conf"|g}' /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf`

Comment: Inspecting the `sed` command. Found few unmatched `'`. The desired `sed` command is: `sed -i '{s|<Directory '"C:\xampp"'>|<Directory '"C:\\xampp\\apache\\conf"'>|g; s|DocumentRoot '"C:\xampp"'|DocumentRoot '"C:\\xampp\\apache\\conf"'|g}' /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf` . Notice a `'` before opening `"` and a `'` after a closing `"` . All `'` must match. I am using a coloring editor to assist me matching the quotes (VScode). Use `grep` to pretest your file matching. Also test `sed` command one instruction at a time.

Comment: I see. After messing around, in order to match completely, I have the following:
`sed -i "{s|${DIRLOC}|<Directory \"${WORKINGDIR}\">|g; s|${ROOTLOC}|DocumentRoot \"${WORKINGDIR}\"|g}" /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf`

This is the result.

`++ sed -i '{s|<Directory "C:\xampp">|<Directory "C:\\xampp\\apache\\conf">|g; s|DocumentRoot "C:\xampp"|DocumentRoot "C:\\xampp\\apache\\conf"|g}' /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf`

It still doesn't change the file.

Comment: Suggesting to test with `grep  '<Directory "C:\xampp">' /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf ` to test for match. Also `grep  'DocumentRoot "C:\xampp"' /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf` . Once both `grep` commands match, the `sed` command will work.

Comment: See reference below:

`++ echo '<Directory "C:\xampp">'
<Directory "C:\xampp">
++ echo 'DocumentRoot "C:\xampp"'
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp"
++ sed -i '{s|<Directory "C:\xampp">|<Directory "C:\\xampp\\apache\\conf">|g; s|DocumentRoot "C:\xampp"|DocumentRoot "C:\\xampp\\apache\\conf"|g}' /c/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf` --- Sadly no go and alludes to my original issue. If I manually make a copy of httpd.conf (named httpd.conf.ORIG, like in the script), remove the if statement and then run... it works. sed replaces, no problem. Sadly, it only messes up if I make a copy within the script.